# について as a topic marker

Tags: particle-は, topic

I don't know if this question is appropriate for this site or not, but I am going to ask this question hoping for clarification.

When I hear について It feels like the declaration or introduction of something and somehow I expect a comment (wathever it is I can understand the sentence immediately.) but when I hear は I immediately think about it as a subject marker.

For example

> りんごについて、食べた。
>   りんごは食べた。

I perceive them differently.

> りんごについて、食べた。 
>   I declare it's about apples. I comment "Ate".
>   Or
>   I declare that it is regarding the apple. I comment "Ate".
>
> りんごは食べた。 
>   I see this as apples ate. 
>   But I know that it is not correct. 
>   I know that it should sound something like what I hear with について.

So my question is:
Is について a topic marker too?
If in my mind I uset について instead of は, but while talking I would say は, would make my sentence weird to someone hearing.

Example:

> 剣ほどの大きさにまで膨らんだ青白い閃光は、情け容赦なく上条(かみじょう)の首へと叩き込まれる。

When reading it like this I get lost when I see は because while subsconsciouly I think about it as the subject marker I consciously know that it is not and I am not sure how to perceive it.

> 剣ほどの大きさにまで膨らんだ青白い閃光について、情け容赦なく上条(かみじょう)の首へと叩き込まれる。

This feels easier for me. 
I literally hear it like this: 
It's about "The flash of light which expanded to the dimension of a sword". I comment "Without any mercy it is being thrust at Kamijo's neck". 
Or
"The flash of light which expanded to the dimension of a sword" I declare it regards this, The comment is "Without any mercy it is being thrust at Kamijo's neck".

The feeling I get with について is:
剣ほどの大きさにまで膨らんだ青白い閃光 is just an introduction and a declaration and it needs a comment, what really matters is what I say about that "情け容赦なく上条(かみじょう)の首へと叩き込まれる。"

1)Would it sound weird as a sentence to a native speaker if instead of は there was について in a case like this?
2)To you natiev speakers, does は sound kind of like について sounds to me?

Comment: I feel weird to use について instead of は as a topic marker.

Comment: I know that it would feel weird to a native speaker, but would the meaning change? 
I think I have to adapt my は to this feeling. 
I was told at the beginning that it was a subject particle and whenever I asked I was told to keep thinking about it as if it always marked the subject. 
Only after I finished college I discovered it was the topic particle and now it's hard for me to think about it differently so I have to re-adapt my thinking. 
Anyway, is my understanding of how は feels correct?  
Just an answer to these 2 questions would help me immensely.

Comment: Do you want to know the usage of は? If so, について isn't related with it. We rarely use について instead of は as a topic marker so I think it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I am just saying how it feels to me. Xについて feels like after that a comment regarding that is coming. No matter what it is I understand it as: It's about X. I comment "sentence".  
While with は it feels as if it's the subject while I know it is not. 
So would that feeling I described be the one you feel with は?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is について a topic marker too?

No. On one hand は has some grammatical function as a topic marker, and on the other hand, について doesn't.

But I think, the meaning of について is indeed somewhat close to the interpretation of topic markers.

---

> 1)Would it sound weird as a sentence to a native speaker if instead of は there was について in a case like this?

Yes. Your example りんごについて、食べた。 can never be a natural phrase. This is because there is no topic nor subject. Instead you can say りんごについて**は**、食べた。 Here, ついては is ついて + は where は is a topic marker. I feel ついては has stronger "regardedness" than は alone.

---

> 2)To you native speakers, does は sound kind of like について sounds to me?

Partially yes. Sometimes は is interpreted to "introduction and comment", but not always. This style of writing is often seen in laws. For example:

> 第百七十六条から前条までの罪の未遂**は**、罰する。 （[刑法 第一七九条](http://law.e-gov.go.jp/htmldata/M40/M40HO045.html#1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000017900000000001000000000000000000)）

Whenever I hear は, I at first think of it as marking a subject, recognizing a topic at the same time. In most cases we don't have problem with it.

Well, as you might know, your example りんごは食べた is the same as りんごは*私が*食べた. Grammatically, the subject is not りんご but 私. I, however, as a native speaker, interpret it more like "The apple is what I ate."

Comment: Thank you  lot for this answer. 
So I have some other questions:
1)"Sometimes は is interpreted to "introduction and comment", but not always." This kind of feels the way I perceive は at times, but not always. I kind of perceve は  as something strictly only connected to a verb (Main verb), I don't feel like it's connected to other parts of  the sentence. Is this correct? Online I found 主題と述語 and it was said that the topic is connected to the end Verb.
2)"Whenever I hear は, I at first think of it as marking a subject, recognizing a topic at the same time.  I see, what if it's a long sentence?

Comment: 1) Yes. Whenever は marks a subject, it can be only connected to a main verb. That is, は can't be used this way in a relative clause. 　 　 2) Sorry but I don't really distinguish short and long sentences, as most native speakers don't.

Comment: I see thanks.  I was told that to natve speakers it sounded like Xについて言えば Is this true?  
To me it feels like what comes after は goes back to what comes before it.  
XはY=Y regards X=X<-Y

Comment: Well, Xについて言えば is close to Xについては. In some cases it is almost the same as Xは. 　 　 And I agree on  "XはY=Y regards X=X<-Y". Whether X is a subject or not, I also feel something like "X<-Y".

Comment: I see. 
Thank you again. 
So would it be correct to say that in XはY,は acts kind of like a divider for the sentence. What comes before は  is divivided from what comes after it in the sense that Xは signals that from after the は until a main verb it all regards X?   
Kind of like Xは (Y) as if X is detached from what comes after it?
So does this mean Xは means something like: Regard X, all of Y until the main predicate?  
Sorry for all this (maybe stupid-sounding) questions, but は is the last big problem that I can't seem to overcome.

Comment: I think your idea is correct. 　 I believe this is what the word "topic" stands for. Once the topic is determined by a topic marker, whole sentence is to somehow describe (or add some information to) the topic. 　 One trifling thing I want to add is that Xは is not always positioned at the very top of a sentence. For example, そこに彼は居た is the same as 彼はそこに居た.

Comment: I see thanks.  I guess I have to keep reading while thinking about counsciously.